# sudo: setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE): Operation not permitted

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, docker, ulimit

seeing this when executing `sudo` from inside a docker container (ubuntu 18.04) when parent host is ubuntu 20.04

```
sudo -i
sudo: setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE): Operation not permitted
root@devops:~#
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

a fix has been applied to sudo 1.8.31p1 and is already in 1.9 however this warning has a work around ... just issue

```
echo "Set disable_coredump false" >> /etc/sudo.conf
```

for details see https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/issues/42